# How do I extend the refracted ray in pst-optic?

Tags: pstricks, pst-optic

I am trying to reproduce Snell's law using `\refractionRay` macro. However the refracted ray that I obtain is 'short' to say and I wish to extend it further. How do I achieve this? Also the documentation is not that detailed or much of the explanation there is vague. I am referring to documentation for `pst-optic` version 1.02. In page 20, it talked about `n1` and `n2` having values 1 and 1.41 respectively. But why is the macro used in this way `\refractionRay(A)(B)(C)(D){1}{4}{E}` and not `\refractionRay(A)(B)(C)(D){1}{1.41}{E}`? and how come sine of beta greater than 1?

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-optic}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}

\pnode(-3.5,0){A}
\pnode(3.5,0){B}
\uput[0](B){$x$}
\pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=lightgray,linecolor=lightgray](-3,0)(3,0)(3,3)(-3,3)(-3,0)
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue]{->}(A)(B)
\rput(-2,-1.5){\Large$n_1$}\rput(-2,1.5){\Large$n_2$}
\pnode(-1,-3){C}
\pnode(0,0){D}
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red]{->}(C)(D)
\refractionRay(C)(D)(A)(B){1}{4}{E}
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red]{->}(D)(E')
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like a bug in the documentation. Only `\lensSPHRay`  uses the predefined values. However yo can get shorter or longer arrows with `pcline`:

```
\pcline[arrowscale=2,linewidth=1pt,linecolor=red,
    nodesepB=-2cm]{->}(E)(E')
```

`nodesep=-2cm` makes the line 2 cm *longer* to the right.

[image]

Comment: This really helped me extend the line. However, I would also like to know what values to pass in \refractionRay if I require n1=1 and n2=1.5 (i.e air to glass)

Comment: `\refractionRay(C)(D)(A)(B){1}{1.5}{E}` if your ray starts in n1 ...